# How can I scrape a fully rendered web page with items loaded on scroll?

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, phantomjs

I want to crawl Google PlayStore ranking pages such as "https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/EDUCATION/collection/topselling_paid"

When I view the page with a browser, it firstly shows 60 apps and shows more apps up to 540 by mouse scrolling and clicking a "show more" button.

I think the page is fully rendered when events such as "mouse scroll", "click a button" are created.

Problem is that I don't know how to generate these events without browsers, therefore I could only scrape the pages which are not fully rendered and contain only 60 apps.

I tried a bellow code with PhantomJS, but did not work at all.

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    url;
url = system.args[1];
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};
page.open(url, function() {            
    page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
        page.evaluate(function() {
            //Shows ranking up to 60th.
            console.log($("a.title").text());

            //Tried scroll mouse. However, cannot render the page.
            for(i=0; i<150; i++){
                console.log(document.body.scrollTop)
                window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
                console.log(document.body.scrollTop)
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            }
            //Expect to show ranking up to 540th.
            console.log($("a.title").text());
        });
        phantom.exit()
    });
});
```

How can I crawl the fully rendered pages?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [CasperJs](http://casperjs.org/). It's good tool to scrap dynamic web page.

> CasperJs is a navigation scripting & testing utility for PhantomJS

You have click event for exemple : [API Documentation](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#click)

Comment: Recommending a tool doesn't solve the problem. CasperJS doesn't magically accomplish this task. Maybe you can show *how* this is possible with CasperJS?

Comment: I have already set the example of the document to do that